# Examples of sequent derivations that uses cut rule that can be modified to not to use cut rule?

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, proof-theory, formal-proofs, sequent-calculus

The cut-elimination theorem states that any sequent calculus derivation that uses the cut rule also has a derivation that does not use the cut rule. I cannot find any explicit examples of such derivations. Are there any?